# determine the Keras's Mnist input shape

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mnist

I have xtrain.shape as

```
(60000, 28, 28)
```

It means 60000 channels with image size 28 * 28

I want to make a keras Sequential model.

## specifying the model shape

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,activation='relu',input_shape=(????)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.summary()
```

what input_shape should looks like?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64,input_shape=(1,28,28)))
```

when I put this I got an following error

```
Error when checking input: expected dense_31_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)
```

why this required 4 dimensions? and how to fix it form code?

Answer (score 2):

> I have xtrain.shape as
>
> ```
> (60000, 28, 28)
> ```
>
> It means 60000 channels with image size 28 * 28

Well, it certainly does not mean that; it means 60000 *samples*, not channels (MNIST is a single-channel dataset).

No need to re-invent the wheel in such cases - have a look at the [MNIST CNN example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) in Keras:

```python
from keras import backend as K

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first': # Theano backend
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:                                         # Tensorflow backend
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

# normalise:
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

# your model:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))  # change to softmax in the final layer
```

where you should also change the activation of the final layer to `softmax` (and most probably add some pooling and flatten layers before the final dense one).

Answer (score 1):

Try to reshape data to (60000, 28, 28, 1) or (60000, 1, 28, 28).

Answer (score 1):

First one,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,activation='relu',input_shape=(60000,28,28)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.summary()
```

Second one,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64,input_shape=(None,60000,28,28)))
```